# Sitemap nodes and query string issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string, sitemap

I want to add some random querystring params to some pages in my site, but for pages currently defined with query strings, `SiteMap.CurrentNode` fails with the new params. Pages/Nodes that are not defined with querystrings don't mind the new params added.

I use the sitemap nodes to build the headers and breadcrumbs.

Is there a way to get `SiteMap.CurrentNode` to show up as what is defined in the sitemap as

```
 "whatever.aspx?definedparam=definedvalue"
```

instead of breaking for

```
"whatever.aspx?definedparam=definedvalue&newparam=dynamicvalue"
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to override the xmlsitemapprovider class:
http://www.nullskull.com/q/10386803/persistence-of-query-string-with-sitemap-url.aspx